# Connecting with PostgreSQL 8.2 using Java

Tags: java, postgresql

When I'm connecting to my database (PostgreSQL 8.2) through JDBC it gives an error ClassNotFound and something related to drivers. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to be more precise. Cut and paste the exact error message here. Chances are you just need to include the drivers in the classpath.

Comment: *"and something related to drivers"* is not a valid Java exception nor a valid Postgres error message.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to put the postgres jdbc driver on your classpath.
You can download it from http://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Latest version 8 or 9 drivers should to (stable) like the 9.0-801 driver. To quote the size :

> If you are using the 1.6 JVM, then you
>   should use the JDBC4 version.

Comment: which version have to download for postgresql8.2 database

Comment: @neha: what's so unclear about the sentence: *"This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver you should be using"* on the download page?

Comment: i have put postgresql.jar at java\jre\ext\postgresql.jar but its not working and also set classpath .;c\postgresql.jar.
it still giving an exception classnotfound().
what should i do now???

Comment: @neha: provide a code example on how you are trying to access it.